# How to refer to the variable being added in a weighted sum?

Tags: mathematics

Consider a simple weighted sum:

[image]

My phrase to describe it is (without the proper math notation):

> The expression corresponds to a weighed sum, where w_i is *the variable being added*.

(So, the weights are delta_i, which add up to one.)

The aim of the phrase is to differentiate w_i from delta_i. However, I am not satisfied with this phrase. Other options I have think of are even worse (and probably wrong):

- the variable upon which the sum is carried out.
- the variable to be summed over.
- the variable being weighted by delta_i.

Any ideas what expression is preferred to be used here?

Comment: I take it you want the 'i' as a subtext? You can use `<sub></sub>` tags for that.

Comment: First of all,  weights are **always** the 'w' term.  Don't cross the beams!  Second, there's no requirement that the summed weights add up to anything.  You can always normalize later if you must.

Comment: Non-mathematician here, but using weighted variable for sales analysis, for the same type of problems (when addressing people unfamiliar with weighted variables) I personally use "weighted variable" and "weight" . Usually people understand.

Answer (score 2):

As in my comment,  the 'w' are the weights;  the deltas are the values.  The deltas are not variables: they are the members of a set delta{1,2,...,n} .

In your text, then,  just write "...sum of the sample set **delta<sub>i</sub>**, weighted by the corresponding weights **w<sub>i</sub>** . "

Comment: Not **always**. In my context, `w` stand for wages, which is the central variable running through out my analysis, and takes prominence to whatever convention in terms of weights exists. Additionally, in many contexts, I have seen omega as weights.

Comment: @luchonacho Traditionally, the weight is applied ***to*** the quantity being summed and therefore it is written before the sample value.  Maybe you should write.  ***a*** <sub>i</sub> ***w*** <sub>i</sub> where ***a*** is the *adjustment* value